# Understanding syntax of multi dimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var test = [[
  [1,2],[2,3],[3,4]
]];
alert(test[[0]].length);
```

This returns me 3, but I cannot understand what this actually mean. How come this result?

Answer (score 2):

There are no multi-dimensional arrays in JavaScript. There are only nested arrays.

```
[            //  test
  [          //    test[0]
    [1,2],   //      test[0][0]
    [2,3],   //      test[0][1]
    [3,4]    //      test[0][2]
  ]          //
]            //
```

As you can see, `test[0]` has a length of three.

And `test[[0]]` is semantically incorrect<sup>(*)</sup> and collapses into `test[0]`.

---

<sup>(*)</sup> The index operator (`[]`) expects a number, like in `test[0]`. If you don't pass a number to it (like in your `test[[0]]` case, where you pass the array `[0]`), a conversion to string will happen first. (This is because of the first note below.)

Arrays are converted to string by joining their members with a comma. `[0].toString()` is `"0"`, and therefore `test[[0]]` is equivalent to `test["0"]`, which is equivalent to `test[0]`.

Notes:

- The square brackets are used for property access as well, so that `test["length"]` is the same as `test.length`.
- Consequently, something horrible like `test[[0]][["length"]])` is equivalent to `test[0].length` and will give you `3`.
- Something like `test[[0,0]]` would be `test["0,0"]` - and since there is no property named `"0,0"` on that array, you will get `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

The array `test[0]` contains three items:

- [1,2]
- [2,3]
- [3,4]

Hence, the result of the `length` is 3.

The length of array `test` is just one, since `test` contains only one array:

- [1,2],[2,3],[3,4]

In fact this is not a multi-dimensional array, it's just an array containing arrays (called a jagged array, or nested array).

Answer (score 0):

test[[0]] is same thing as test[0] and test[0] is an array

```
[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]
```

consisting of these elements.

if you want to access ,for instance, `[2,3]` you need to use this syntax:

```
test[0][1]
```

and `test[0][1].length` will give you 2.

Comment: if these syntaxes are same i.e. test[[0]] and test[0] then why is this supported?

Comment: @PatrickHofman No, it converts `[0]` to string, which is why `test[[0]]` works and `test[[0,0]]` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you want get the length of first arrays length then write

```
alert(test[0][0].length);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a nested array. An array of arrays.

It will be more clear if you expand your example:

```
var test = [
    [
        [1,2],[2,3],[3,4]
    ], 
    [
        [5,6],[7,8],[9,9],[6,7]
    ], 
];
alert(test[[1]].length);
```

Now, your test is an array of two arrays. The first one of which is an array of 3 arrays. The second one is an array of 4 arrays.

Now, `test.length` is 2. `test[0].length` is 3. `test[1].length` is 4. `[[n]]` just collapses.

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/6H7Lj/***